# vb.net combox box within a datagrid

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a combobox with a datagrid, but I'd like the user to be able to type into the combobox like usual; At the minute it's a fixed dropdown. Here is my code:

```
  Dim NewColumn As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn() 'Declare new DGV CC

    With NewColumn 'Set Properties
        .DataPropertyName = "NewColumn" 'Name
        .HeaderText = "New Column" 'Heading
        .DropDownWidth = 160 'Width Of DropDown Box
        .Width = 90 'Display Width
        '.MaxDropDownItems = 5 'How Many Items To Drop Down At A Time
        .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat 'Appearance
        .DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox

        .Items.Add("Screw Fix 1") 'Add Some Text Items
        .Items.Add("Fix 1")
        .Items.Add("3 Stone")
        .Items.Add("34 Stone")
        .Items.Add("5")
        .Items.Add("6")
        .Items.Add("7")
        .Items.Add("8")
        .Items.Add("9")
        .Items.Add("10")
    End With
    dgDetails.Columns.Add(NewColumn) 'Add The Column
```

Comment: Not sure why that got marked down ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't natively you need to handle two events

The first to allow the user to type in the new value

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    Dim c As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
    If c IsNot Nothing Then
        c.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
    End If
End Sub
```

The second to actually insert the new value

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handels dataGridView1.CellValidating
    Dim comboBoxColumn As DataGridView.Column = dataGridView1.Columns("yourColumnName")
    If e.ColumnIndex = comboBoxColumn.Index Then
        Dim eFV As Object = e.FormattedValue
        If Not comboBoxColumn.Items.Contains(eFV) Then
            comboBoxColumn.Items.Add(eFV)
                    comboBoxColumn.SelectedIndex = ComboBox.Items.Count - 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - I've added in that code but comboBoxColumn is not defined need to define it somehow?

Comment: @Shane, that's the column that your combo box is located in.

Comment: Yeah that's still not making sense, how do i reference it, I've tried stuff like Dim comboBoxColumn = dgDetails.Columns(2)

Comment: ah gotcha, gimme a minute then check back :D

Comment: Hi yeah almost there, when a new item is added it goes to the bottom of the combobox and it's not selected, how do I reference that? Selected index property is not available - sorry to be a pain, and thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, have you tested that code, becuase I can't get it to work :-( It says items is not a member of DataGridViewColumn if I then amend it to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn then the selectedindex doesn't work - grrr

Comment: Ah got it working now, done edits above - thank you so much for your help! :-)